# How to properly return result from a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, return, dropbox

It's my first posting here so sorry if I'm not giving enough information about my problem. I'm not that familiar with coding but I'm trying to get this function to return the url of files in my dropbox account:

```
var imgUrl = function(path) {
    dropbox({
        resource: 'sharing/list_shared_links',
        parameters: {
            'path': '/' + path
        }
    }, (err, result, response) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        res = result.links[0].url;
        res = res.replace('dl=0', 'dl=1');
        return res;
    });
}

console.log(imgUrl("img/tilesets/Inside_A1.png")); //undefined
```

But `console.log(imgUrl("img/tilesets/Inside_A1.png"));` for example, shows undefined. I does give the url when I change `return res` to `return console.log(res)` but I can't make it give the result without console.log. Can someone please tell me how to return the url when `imgUrl(path)` is used?

Comment: You should learn how callbacks works. Code that you written is asynchronous. Read about it [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced?gi=6cb5c33a78c9)

Comment: I assume the dropbox call to the file is asynchronous, so when you execute your imgUrl method it wont wait for the result but it returns undefined which is the default return value of functions in JavaScript.